# How to remove icon programatically (Android)

Tags: android

By remove the below intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml, it can remove the icon after install.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

But i have try the below when on Boot than remove the Icon, but the icon still remain after reboot. I have add the permission, and this reboot receiver is work.

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PackageManager p = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager(); 
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.example.removeicon","com.example.removeicon.LauncherActivity");
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    }
}
```

Or Put the Boot on service and AndroidManifest.xml intent-filter is not remove, the service is run and work.

```
package com.example.removeicon;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.example.removeicon","com.example.removeicon.LauncherActivity");
        p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        startService();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by remove icon, and what is the use case you are trying to achieve?

Comment: first make sure your `BootBroadcastReceiver` is executing on device reboot or not?  by using logs

Comment: BootBroadcastReceiver is work, if i call the service the service will run correctly.

Comment: Remove icon, mean the application icon will no display after reboot the Android device.

Comment: @user1865039 : then put your  code for removing icon inside service instead of BootBroadcastReceiver

Comment: @user1865039: your code is right for removing icon so try it inside  service

Comment: I think is something missing, I use getComponentName() in mainActivity, the value is ComponentInfo{com.example.removeicon/com.example.removeicon.MainActivity} is and the name assign is ComponentInfo{com.example.removeicon/com.example.removeicon.LauncherActivity} that is correct assign right?

Comment: i found out why already, is the name not correct change LauncherActivity to MainActivity...Than it work. Thks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.example.removeicon","com.example.removeicon.LauncherActivity");
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, 
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

**Note that the icon may not be gone until the next reboot.**

Comment: The getComponentName() i have try, The method getComponentName() is undefined for the type BootBroadcastReceiver

Comment: use context.getComponentName()

Answer (score 2):

try this below code, this one worked for me

```
PackageManager p = ctx.getPackageManager(); 
         p.setComponentEnabledSetting(((Activity)ctx).getComponentName(),
         PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```